# Sliding CSS Animation not flipping in correct area

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to create a CSS animation that has a bird slide to the right, flip and slide back to the left and flip again. And repeat... Like the bird is running back and forth.

Right now it flips, slides and doesn't like like it should.
[Here is the CodePen](http://codepen.io/aculbreth/pen/dPXKeZ)

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="fifth">
 <div id="GoRight">
   <p>... Loading</p>
 </div>
 <div id="TurnGoLeft"></div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    .fifth h2 {
    margin-top: 130px;
}
.fifth #GoRight{
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 14px;
}
.fifth #GoRight p{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #1886c7;
    font-family: "Effra Regular", "Droid Sans", Arial, serif;
}
.fifth #TurnGoLeft {
  width: 110px; 
  height: 66px;
  background-image: url("http://goo.gl/BaIPWx");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  left: 60px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: slideflip, flipslide 2s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideflip {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 110px; 
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 20%;
    width: 110px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipslide {
  50% {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 110px; 
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    margin-left: 20%;
    width: 110px;
  }
}
```

Any help or insight would be really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Check this out http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNeKmJ ... let me know it it helps you to post it as an answer

Comment: I think you're going to need more keyframes in order to achieve this (i'm no expert). But from playing around I'm pretty sure you'll need one animation one way (0-50%) and another (50-100%) for going back

Comment: @Danko Thank you so much! This works perfectly! Also can you post it as an answer

Comment: Ah, I was going for a bit more speed, I didn't fully finish it as you put one up. [Demo](http://codepen.io/Ruddy/pen/dPXKwd)

Comment: @Ruddy just nice ... I change my code a little bit based on yours to avoid the first flipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you can solve it is not using `alternate` and instead create just one animation and take some steps to do the **left to right**  and the **flip**:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideflip {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: 20%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  45% {
    margin-left: 20%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  80% {
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

### [CodepenDemo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbxyPV)

---

<sub>Codepen and amount of % changed from the posted one on my commentary, based on the solution of @Ruddy that helps to avoid the flip at the first step of loaded the animation</sub>